# Trial version sonar PLSQL Plugin

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to sonar PL/SQL plug in .
I would like to use PL/SQL plug in from sonar for analysis of my pLSQL code base.

I am working on a POC. So i need the trial version of the same.

But using the below website , i am not able to get a trial key before installing the free software.
http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/plsql/
Can anybody help me , if he/she has worked on a trial version of sonar plsql plugin.

Thanks,
Sandip

Comment: landed on the same problem...people only with organization email id can get the key for trial versions

Answer (score 2):

As this is explained on the page, you have to [fill a dedicated form](http://www.sonarsource.com/get-contact-sf/?Product__c=PL/SQL&Request_Type__c=Request%20an%20evaluation%20license%20key) to ask for a trial key.

Then SonarSource will contact you and will ask you for some information about your installation, which implies that you already have installed Sonar on a server.

Comment: +1 - Same thing happened here. They asked for more details, and then sent me all three trial licenses. Just that they took 2 days to reply :-)

PS: Your answer should be marked as the correct one